# Equivalence between different formulations of QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I have looked at Greiner's book on QED, where he uses the Feynman propagator approach for QED. He solves a lot of things and calculates several processes without "second quantisation" (and without ever introducing path integrals), it is all basically a classical field theory. In older books in QED however, the second quantisation procedure is used and they take the classical theory and quantise it promoting fields to operators and so on.

My question is: Why are both approaches equivalent (are they?), it is not obvious to me that they should produce the same results, they look quite different to me: One is the noncommutative version of the other in some sense. Is there a proof, or an argumentation on why they should be equivalent, or some intuition behind this idea?